# Separate all EditText with non Empty value by a comma

Tags: java, android-edittext

I'm a beginner in java and sql and I want to sort some information of my table.
I have connected the database to my java project. I want to take all the values of EditText in one column of my table. I want to take all non Empty values and separate them by a comma " ,". The problem is that it takes all the values of the EditText even when they are empty.

I'm looking for this kind of result in my table :

Column : Manque

Row    : Example Value 1, Example Value 3, Example Value 7

But actually I have this,

Column : Manque

Row    : Example Value 1, , Example Value 3, , , , Example Value 7

'''

```
private Controle3 controle3;

private  void init() {
    nb1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nb1);
    nb2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nb2);
    nb3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nb3);
    nb4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nb4);
    nb5 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nb5);
    nb6 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nb6);
    nb7 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nb7);
    nb8 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nb8);
    nb9 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nb9);
    nb10 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nb10);
    nb11 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nb11);
    nb12 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nb12);
    nb13 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nb13);
    nb14 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nb14);
    nb15 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nb15);
    nb16 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nb16);
    nb17 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nb17);
    nb18 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nb18);
    nb19 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nb19);
    nb20 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nb20);
    nb21 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nb21);
    nb22 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nb22);
    nb23 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nb23);
    nb24 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nb24);



    ecouteValidation();
    this.controle3 = Controle3.getInstance(this);
    recupProfil();


}





private void ecouteValidation(){
    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.btnValid)).setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Toast.makeText(FirstActivity.this, "test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //Log.d("message", "clic ok sur le bouton Valid ******************");
            String immatriculation = null;
            String name = null;
            String manque = null;

                        try {
                            immatriculation = txtImmat.getText().toString();
                            name = txtname.getText().toString();




                        } catch (Exception e) {};

            if(nb1.getText().toString().isEmpty() && nb2.getText().toString().isEmpty() && nb3.getText().toString().isEmpty() && nb4.getText().toString().isEmpty() && nb5.getText().toString().isEmpty() && nb6.getText().toString().isEmpty() && nb7.getText().toString().isEmpty() && nb8.getText().toString().isEmpty() && nb9.getText().toString().isEmpty() && nb10.getText().toString().isEmpty() && nb11.getText().toString().isEmpty() && nb12.getText().toString().isEmpty() && nb13.getText().toString().isEmpty() && nb14.getText().toString().isEmpty() && nb15.getText().toString().isEmpty() && nb16.getText().toString().isEmpty() && nb17.getText().toString().isEmpty() && nb18.getText().toString().isEmpty() && nb19.getText().toString().isEmpty() && nb20.getText().toString().isEmpty() && nb21.getText().toString().isEmpty() && nb22.getText().toString().isEmpty() && nb23.getText().toString().isEmpty() && nb24.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
                manque =  "COMPLET";
            }else {

                for(nb1.getText().toString().isEmpty()){


                    manque = nb1.getText().toString() + nb2.getText().toString() + " " + nb3.getText().toString() + " " + nb4.getText().toString() + " " + nb5.getText().toString() + " " + nb6.getText().toString() + " " + nb7.getText().toString() + " " + nb8.getText().toString() + " " + nb9.getText().toString() + " " + nb10.getText().toString() + " " + nb11.getText().toString() + " " + nb12.getText().toString() + " " + nb13.getText().toString() + " " + nb14.getText().toString() + " " + nb15.getText().toString() + " " + nb16.getText().toString() + " " + nb17.getText().toString() + " " + nb18.getText().toString() + " " + nb19.getText().toString() + " " + nb20.getText().toString() + " " + nb21.getText().toString() + " " + nb22.getText().toString() + " " + nb23.getText().toString() + " " + nb24.getText().toString();
                }
            }






                        if (name.isEmpty() || immatriculation.isEmpty()) {
                            Toast.makeText(MaterielVSLActivity.this, "Saisie incorrecte", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            afficheResult(immatriculation, name, manque);
                            Toast.makeText(MaterielVSLActivity.this, "OK", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });

            }

            /**
             * Affichage du message
             *
             */
            private void afficheResult(String immatriculation, String name, String manque){
                this.controle3.creerProfil(immatriculation, name, manque, this);
            }
```

}'''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add all your EditTexts to an array

```
EditText[] editTexts ={nb1,nb2,nb3...};
String content;
```

and loop the array check if the item content is not empty add it to the content

```
for(EditText myEditText : editTexts){
    if(!myEditText.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
        content += myEditText.getText().toString() + ","
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay thank you very much for your answer. But how can I set the second part to the code to "manque" ?